# A set containing one element is an open set. Why?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

I asked a question last night about proving that a discrete metric space is both open and closed. Once or twice it was mentioned that a set that contains only one element is open. I'd like to know:

**a)** is that always true?

**b)** why?

An explanation that is both a proof and a simple breakdown of it would be most helpful.

Comment: The proof is little more than "What is the definition of 'open'? What is the definition of 'discrete'?"

Comment: It's true in discrete spaces (every subset of a discrete space is open and closed), not in general. However, in general, a singleton set is open iff the point it contains is an isolated point.

Comment: he may want to know why the discrete metric space has a discrete topology.

Comment: @magguu *she and no.

Comment: Any topological space is both open and closed.  One of the definitions of a topology is that the empty set and the entire set are both open sets, and therefore both closed.  You may need to change the first sentence of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, it is *not* the case that single-element sets are open.  For example, in the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, the one induced by the usual metric, single-element sets are *not* open; open sets are unions of open intervals, and every open set (except $\varnothing$) is infinite.

---

Say we have a metric space with the so-called "discrete" metric $d$.  Recall that this means that $$d(x,y) = \begin{cases} 0, \text{if $x = y$}\\ 1, \text{if $x\ne y$}\end{cases}$$

A metric space has a natural topology "induced by" its metric.
The "metric topology" induced by the metric $d$ is the one that has as its basis all "balls" $N_{d,\epsilon}(x)$ where $$N_{d,\epsilon}(x) = \{ p \mid d(x,p) < \epsilon\}.$$

"Basis" here means that a set is open if and only if it is a union of some of these balls.

The topology induced on $\Bbb R^n$ by its usual metric is exactly the usual topology for $\Bbb R^n$.  But for an unusual metric such as the discrete metric, the situation is different.

Observe that in the discrete metric $d$, $N_{d,1/2}(x) = \{x\}$, because $x$ itself is the only point $p$ such that $d(x,p) < \frac12$.  So each $\{x\}$ is a basis element and is therefore open in the metric topology induced by $d$.

Since any union of open sets is open, and any set at all is a union of sets of the form $\{x\}$, we conclude that any set at all is open in the  topology induced by the discrete metric $d$.

This is why this metric $d$ is called the "discrete" metric: the topology it induces is the discrete topology.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you mean a) and b) in general or just in a discrete metric space so let me answer for both cases

A) for the discrete metric space it is always true by definition. for a general topology it is not

B) consider the ball $B(x,1/2)$. it is a basic open set and contains only one point $x$. if the space is not discrete metric then Real numbers give you an example of why a singleton is not open.